# Eclipse Package Explorer Zoom?

Tags: eclipse, configuration

Configuring Eclipse to look exactly how you want is a tough job I've found, therefore I'm not going to attempt to do this myself.

I'd like to 'zoom out' of the *Package Explorer* side bar? You see, I like only having my code on the screen with a small section for the files in the project - however I can never see the full path of the file or package I'm currently in because of this. Is there a way to keep the 'main screen' normal, but zoom out of the *Package Explorer* by about 50%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an exact fit, but I would recommend using **[fast views](http://www.tomcornilliac.com/2007/08/how-to-use-eclipse-fast-view/)**

It minimizes your package explorer view, and you can recall it in order to display with a *large* size, for you to... explorer. Once you click anywhere outside the fast view, it disappear.
Note: to really gain as much space as possible, [since Eclipse3.6M2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=278064), you can hide the fast view bar if empty.