# Eclipse - changing font size in project/package explorer

Tags: linux, eclipse, configuration

I'm using two environments, one with 24" screen, second one with 15". I need default font size of content of project/package explorer in the first one, but small font size for the other one.

Is there any way how to change it within eclipse? I mean not within operating system ? Because it always influences other font size on desktop. I'm reffering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896872/eclipse-package-explorer-zoom) question.

If there is no way, please describe how would you do it in Linux - distribution independently.

Comment: Hmm... Good question. BTW- I'd expect to have +- the same physical (as in millimetres) font size on both, and doesn't the difference of screen resolutions compensate for that on its own?

Comment: Resolution compensates it but on laptop you really need more space for editor and long file names and hierarchies ...you know...It would really help. Moreover I couldn't get used to the fast view window feature.

Comment: Check out this Post, [this will solve your problem (Solution with Pictures)][1]
Thanks.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134826/eclipse-fonts-zoom-out-zoom-in-pluginvery-helpful-for-developers/21134906#21134906

Answer (score 18):

I have a 17 inch Mac Book Pro which is frequently hooked up to 27 inch high res display and the font size in the package explorer was way too small. Eclipse is supposed to respect the OS settings but it turns out on Mac OS X the default setting for eclipse is to use small Fonts rather than the standard os fonts.

on Mac OS X you can change edit the eclipse.ini file and remove `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts` restart eclipse and presto you will find that your package explorer looks brilliant with reasonable sized fonts.

You make have to use the Finder option "Show Contents" on the Eclipse.app to find the eclipse.ini file, and, the smallFonts line may occur more than once in the .ini file.

Comment: Somewhere along the line, the STS.ini moved to **`/Users/{user}/sts-bundle/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse`**

Comment: @Jim, how is that connected to the answer?

Comment: STS is Eclipse with (many) modifications, and in STS, sts.ini is equivalent to eclipse.ini, so anyone else who comes along looking for the answer to this can save some time

Comment: removing the below line worked for me .In STS , sts.app looks like an icon but its a directory. 
/STS/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/STS.ini 
Remove this line.
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS X, download TinkerTool from http://bresink.de/osx/TinkerTool.html and then change the font size for "Help tags".

That changed the font size of package explorer for me. :)

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't work for me. Which OSX and Eclipse version are you using? Thanks for pointing me toward TinkerTool, by the way! Love this thing.

Comment: Changing the system font size with TinkerTool appears to help.

Answer (score 2):

I can say pretty confidently that you cannot change that font size from within eclipse, only choice is on the operating system. And on ubuntu you are able to change that font size.

Answer (score 2):

For windows check below link:

> Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > View
> and Editor Folders > Tree and Table font for views

https://www.bootng.com/2021/01/change-project-explorer-tree-view-font.html

Answer (score 1):

I work in Android development. I have ADT installed which comes which eclipse. The Windows about states that the eclipse installed has following components.

```
This product includes Eclipse Platform, JDT, CDT, EMF, GEF and WTP,
```

and Version : 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
and BuildID : M20130204-1200

With the above version, I am able to change the font within eclipse. The process to change the font is very simple

```
1) Click on Window menu.
2) Click on Preferences sub menu.
3) Open General tab. (Left navigation)
4) Open Appearances sub tab. (Left navigation)
5) Click on Colors and Font option. (Left navigation)
6) Expand Basic option. (Right panel)
7) Click on Text Font (last option in Basic option)
8) Click on Edit Button.
9) Change the font which you want.
```

The screen shot of above option looks like...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For linux: Check out this link, it was very useful to me! I'm using the author's favourite option and works seamlessly.

http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse Oxygen on Sierra, deleting
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
from Eclipse.app » Contents » Eclipse » eclipse.ini
didn't change anything visible

Answer (score 0):

[Change Project Explorer font size in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdikh.png)

1. Goto Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colours and Fonts > View and Editor Folders > Tree and Table font for views
2. Click Edit and change the font size