# Change the fonts in the PyDev Package Explorer

Tags: pydev, liclipse

How do I change the fonts used in the LiClipse PyDev Package Explorer?  I find them a little bit on the small side.

Answer (score 0):

There's no special configuration inside Eclipse for that... (LiClipse/PyDev just provides what's default in Eclipse here).

For more information and workarounds see:

[Eclipse - changing font size in project/package explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466247/eclipse-changing-font-size-in-project-package-explorer)

[I cannot change the font size of package explorer in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529727/i-cannot-change-the-font-size-of-package-explorer-eclipse)

[How can I configure the font size for the tree item in the package explorer in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124629/how-can-i-configure-the-font-size-for-the-tree-item-in-the-package-explorer-in-e)